# Which to Accept? Multiple Accurate Different/Incomplete Answers

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Maybe I'm just not smart enough to judge the answers to the [most recent question I asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/51700/secure-validation-of-wp-editor-in-theme-options), but it seems to me that both answers are correct, unique, and *not* mutually exclusive.

I don't want to be one of those horrible people with a low accept rate, but I also feel bad accepting one answer over the other (and accidentally implying than the unaccepted answer is wrong). If forced to choose, I think I know which one I'd accept, but I can't even really articulate why.

I'm sure I'm not the only person who this happens to. I see a similar issue when two people both half-answer a question where neither answer is the complete solution.

Which answer do I accept?

Comment: Upvote one, accept another. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Few simple suggestions I roughly stick with:

1. Upvote answers that were useful (separately from considering which one accept).
2. If you have several complete answers (using different approaches or something) accept the one that helped you with your specific issue, comment that it is not necessarily *the* answer for others.
3. If no answers are complete and or helped you - don't accept any. You can comment, suggesting to move answers towards completion, offer a bounty or post your own answer if you have solution by that time.

Comment: I suspect that part of the issue here is that the WPSE community isn't especially willing to edit existing answers to *add content* to them (edits/clarifications? yes; but adding to the *substance* of the answer? Not so much, in my experience.) So, rather than edit a *partial* answer to add the completing content, someone will simply post a *complimentary* answer. This is probably an opportunity for us to improve how we *as a community* provide answers to questions.

Comment: Very good advice. I'll keep in mind the editing answers part too, @chip. That makes sense to me.